# Any way for generic type T for 2 parameters forcing the same type?

Tags: kotlin

I want to write a function like this, where T must be the same data-type for both variables, but can be anything as long as they are the same.

```
fun <T> doSomething(var1: T, var2: T) {}
```

When I write this, it will work with any two variables, such as

```
doSomething(5, listOf<Thread>())
```

The current assumption is it assumes that since int and list are different, that T is now considered Any?

Is there any way to make this work?  A coworker is using Swift and it works as expected for him, failing to compile if either item is a different type.

I tried using reified functions as well, but same problem.  It only causes a compile error if I explicitly added the reified class at the start, it just assumes it's any otherwise.

E.G.

```
inline fun <reified T> doSomething(var1: T, var2: T) { }

doSomething(1,"2") <-- unwanted compile
doSomething<String>(1,"2") <-- Will not compile
```

But I don't want to only have the function work if the person remembers to add the explicit type on it...

Comment: Good question, I don't think a solution, maybe a ```refied T out Any``` i think this way the type will need to be explicity

Comment: instead of specifying the generic type in the function body, if you specify it in the class declaration wouldn't it solve your problem?

Comment: What would the syntax on that be,  I can't get anything that seems to compile? This won't... <reified T: <out Any>>

Comment: This is in a companion object for a sealed class, I don't think I can put it on the class...  Anything that compiles anyway doesn't force the companion to be the same types

Comment: Can you add a use case of this feature? This way we can understand if we can fix the problem differently. What are you going to to with these two parameters, provided that they are of the same type?

Comment: What you're describing cannot be done at compile time. What is wrong with specifying the type when you call the function? What if they are different types that implement the same interface? What if one of them is a subclass with some minor change?

Comment: If you can submit a list and int you might introduce programming errors where you thought they were the same type but they weren't and you might not realize the error until something goes wrong.  If it forced the type then you could avoid some errors, but with reified it's only optional not required.  Swift does it at compile time so I thought maybe Kotlin could.  If this truly can't be done you can answer as that I and I can accept it.

Comment: @gpunto I'm writing a sealed class to do comparisons and return results and I only want to allow the comparison if the two submitted items are the same type

Comment: What could you possibly do (that doesn't involve reflection) by incorrectly assuming they are the same type? Within the function, since it's generic, it will treat them both as `Any` anyway. Just trying to understand the use case. I don't really know Swift, but is your coworker using `inout` parameters? Otherwise, I would be surprised if it imposed a restriction that subclasses of a type are not allowed.

Comment: Subclasses might have worked, but when he went doSomething(1, "5") it failed to compile.   doSomething(mutablieList, list) probably would have worked?  They weren't using in/outs

If you as the programmer accidentally decide to compare an int and string it will always fail.  If you didn't realize they were different types based off names, it might never work as expected.  I'm just trying to clean up the use of some booleans so things read easier specifically around comparisons.  Thought it would be cool if I could have it work for all types instead of just types I add.

Comment: Ah ha!  Comparable<T> worked.  It won't let me do doSomething(1, "2") now.

Comment: I deleted my comment because I had a poor example. You wouldn't be able to do `doSomething<Number>` since none of the primitives implement `Comparable<Number>`. But at least it enforces types that are both comparable with each other, which in the case of primitives means they have to be the same type.

Comment: Oh I see... so it will work for some classes (primatives) but it won't work for everything... but something is better than nothing where I was going to need to write them out one by one?  Really I imagine this will mostly just be primatives and lists for my use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like maybe your coworker is adding associated type constraints. Kotlin doesn't have associated types, but it might be similar to specifying your Kotlin function with something like this:

```
fun <T> doSomething(var1: Comparable<T>, var2: Comparable<T>)
```

which in Kotlin would enforce the same type for primitives, for instance `doSomething(3, 4)`. `doSomething(4, "x")` would fail to compile because the arguments do not both implement a Comparable of the same type.

If you also need to handle collections, you can overload the function:

```
fun <T> doSomething(var1: Iterable<Comparable<T>>, var2: Iterable<Comparable<T>>)
```

This probably covers most of the use cases you described in the comments.

Comment: This works perfectly for how I want to use it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't like comparable approach because it won't work for all types. I think this will do the trick, although has strange syntax:

```
fun <T> doSomething(var1: T) = fun(var2: T) {
  println("Hello $var1 and $var2")
}

fun te() {
  doSomething(42)("Text") // Error
  doSomething(42)(78) // OK
}
```

You can also easily expand it:

```
fun <T> doSomething(var1: T) = fun(var2: T) = fun(var3: T) {
  println("Hello $var1 and $var2 and $var3")
}
```

Comment: That does work, but I really don't like that syntax...  I will probably keep it around for items that don't implement comparable though if the need arises